# storing user data and keep it during production environment

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I am building an MVP for my services on Django, where users can log in/register and use the services. But in case I want to drastically change my product, how will I save and retrieve the data given by users when I relaunch my website?
What tips will you give to keep the user data and reuse it, when I deploy my website with the different version as an MVP and later full version.

Comment: Have you tried going over the django tutorials?

Comment: I did. But how can I back up the data in case something wrong happen?